# Python Flask how to print text from a python script to a webpage instead of the console

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am a beginner in web programming using Flask in Python. I want to print the console output of a python script to a webpage. Sample code is:

```
>  @app.route('/register', methods=["POST"]) def register():
>     ip_address = request.form.get("IP_ADDRESS")
>     router_location = request.form.get("Routers_Location")
>     def g():
>         output = xyz.main(ip_address, router_location)
>         for line in output:
>             yield line
>     return Response(g(), mimetype='text/html')
```

Where xyz is the python script that I am importing in the above code and main() contains few print statements. Currently, I am using list to have the print statements appended to it and return back to the caller function.

I need to print all the print statements to a web page as it prints on the console. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, this is a bit hard to do. There are tons of ways to do this, but the one you probably want depends on a lot of other factors you didn't include. So it would be helpful to include information like how you set up your flask, when you want to run this code, etc.

Comment: A good way to write code is to try to split up the things you are doing into smaller parts and handle them separately. In your case, seems like you are doing three main things: getting some input, doing something interesting with that input (so called "business logic"), and then displaying that output to a webpage. Those three things can be separated, and your code will be easier to work with if you do so.

Comment: If all you want to do is print text to a page, well, the flask Quickstart gives a great example: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Comment: @GarrettMotzner I have modified my question.